# Follow Turblinks.visit() in rails controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a `create.js.erb` template with the following:

```
<% if @conversation.errors.any? %>
  $("#form").html("<%= j render(partial: 'form') %>");
<% else %>
  Turbolinks.visit("<%= conversation_url @conversation %>");
<% end %>
```

I can test the sad path easily using `assert_select_jquery` like so:

```
test 'sad path' do
  # code that causes failure ommitted

  # test that the error explanation div appears
  assert_select_jquery :html, '#form' do
    assert_select 'li', "Body can't be blank"
  end  
end
```

I'm having trouble testing the happy path:

```
test "happy path" do
  post conversations_url, params: { conversation: attrs }, xhr: true

  # Test that Turbolinks takes us to 
  # the mailbox after successful post 
  assert_select '.flash', "Message sent successfully."
end
```

The test fails because the flash div containing the success message only appears after the Turbolinks call. The best I can do so far is test that the response body contains a call to `Turblinks.visit()`:

```
expected_response = "Turbolinks.visit(\"#{conversation_url conversation}\");"
assert_match /#{expected_response}/, response.body.chomp
```

But this is totally gross. Is there a rails way for telling controller tests to execute any Turblinks directives contained in js.erb files that might be rendered during the request?

```
execute_javascript_on_page
assert_select :h1, 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a browser to execute JavaScript so you need a browser test with something like [capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara). I'm not sure which Rails version you use but in Rails 5 browser tests are provided by default. See [*System Testing*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing) in Rails Guides. In previous versions, you need to install `capybara` yourself.

That being said, I do **not** think testing for a call to `Turbolinks.visit` is *that* bad. My only concern is that it might be a bit unreadable so I'd define a custom assertion like:

```
def assert_turbolinks_visit(target_url)
  assert_match(%r{Turbolinks.visit("#{target_url}")}, response.body)
end
```

and then use it like:

```
assert_turbolinks_visit(conversation_url(conversation))
```

It might get more problematic if the argument to `Turbolinks.visit` isn't a literal. In this case, a browser test may be necessary.